# Javascript how to set null/undefined values in an Object to an empty string

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object where some fields have a value of `null` or `undefined`.
Is there a nice quick way to change these values to an empty string `''` using Javascript or Lodash?

Example input:

```
{
  a: '23',
  b: 'Red',
  c: null,
}
```

Example output:

```
{
  a: '23',
  b: 'Red',
  c: '',
}
```

NOTE: I do NOT want to remove these fields with values of `null` or `undefined`, I want to keep them in the object but change their values to the empty string `''`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) to iterate the values and replace them, and [`_.isNil()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isNil) to check if a value is `null` or `undefined`:

```js
const obj = {
  a: '23',
  b: 'Red',
  c: null,
}

const result = _.mapValues(obj, v => _.isNil(v) ? '' : v)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is very nice thank you! Accepting this answer instead as it is shorter and easier to read

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `Object.keys()` and `.forEach()`:

```
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(key, index) {
  if (this[key] == null) this[key] = "";
}, yourObject);
```

The `==` comparison will check for both `null` and `undefined`. Passing `yourObject` as the second parameter to `.forEach()` will cause `this` to be bound to it inside the callback function.

*edit* — originally I wrote this as an `=>` function, but that won't work because we need `this` to work in the traditional way.

Comment: @tnoel999888 without seeing your actual code it's going to be hard to help. You can edit it into your question.

Comment: ah fair enough, edited the post to include my actual code

Comment: @tnoel999888 oh oh sorry, my bad; it'll need an old-style function. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @tnoel999888 sorry I don't use `=>` functions in my own code due to various particular constraints I'm under, so I'm not really used to thinking about how they work etc :)

Comment: Thanks working now! Accepted answer. Also would it be possible instead of having both arguments `(key, index)` i could just have one say `field` and then it becomes `if (field == null) field = "";`?

Comment: @tnoel999888 no, that wouldn't work: you need the code to explicitly update the property value on the object. It's a little ugly. You don't need the `index` parameter however so you can leave that off since the function doesn't use it.